# Excel Sequence (Occurrences in a row)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, spreadsheet

Is there a way to count cells in a column that have numbers one after the other?

[image: Excel Scoring System]

So from the image player 1 got 3 points in a row, player two got 4 points in a row, can excel workout these points are an occurrence( a streak ) of points?

Not the total amount of points but the highest streak, I have researched but found nothing that could provide this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Excel drop down option does not allow you to change the size or other formatting options. However, you can use a workaround involving a combo box. http://access-excel.tips/excel-data-validation-combo-box/